# Return value instead of promise in asynchronous javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, fetch-api

Hello I need to asynchronously fetch some data then return it to an exported module. I was wondering if it was possible to return anything besides a promise with asynchronous functions so that you could export them as modules. Here is an example of what I mean:

```
module.exports = async (videoId) => {
  const test = await fetchPage({url: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${videoId}`,})
  return test;
}
```

This code obviously returns a promise and I was wondering if there was anyway to break the cycle of promises once the first promise is created asynchronously? Or am I supposed to just refactor my code around the promises?

Comment: No, it is not possible. A promise represents the _eventual value_ which is exactly what you want to return.

Comment: @elclanrs Ah okay so the chain cannot be broken. Any general tips on refactoring my code to function well with promises?

Answer (score -1):

also you could just write.

```
module.exports = (videoId) => {
   return fetchPage({url: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${videoId}`,})
}
```

This would remove the awaiting and then wrapping the promise

Comment: That's not at all what it would do. Removing the `await` still leaves `fetchPage` returning a promise.